# Pass pure text to angular component, access ng-content value on typescript level

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-component',
    template: ``,
})
export class MyComponent {
    content: string;
}
```

I want content property to be `Hello World` when I use my component like this:

```
<app-my-component>Hello World</app-my-component>
```

How can I make it happen?

Comment: And it's not possible to take as a `@Input` instead?

Comment: @JonasMH unfortunately no

Comment: why is it you cannot use @Input just so its easier how to solve this. you could use <ng-content> but you would have to wrap it with with a dom element to then get the data via  innerHtml

Comment: really, what is bad or missing in using @Input?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Content projection (ng-content) to display the text given by the parent component and inject ElementRef to get the value in your typescript file.

my-component.component.ts

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    content: string;

    constructor(private elt: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.content = this.elt.nativeElement.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        console.log("content:", this.content);
    }
}
```

my-component.component.html

```html
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

parent-component.component.html

```html
<my-component>My text</my-component>
```

Edit: You may also use `@Input` if you project the content in a `ng-container`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add  to the template, then retrieve the content in the component as such.
Add ElementRef to your constructor injections
this.content = this.elementRef.nativeElement.textContent;

If you don't want to see  in your template, you can wrap with another element which you then clear.

If someone has a way of doing this without having  in the template please share.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to pass this data in your component you have to use @Input() in it.

So you would have :

```
export class MyComponent {
    @Input() content;
}
```

Then in the template you would write :

```
<app-my-component [content]="Hello World"></app-my-component>
```

And if you don't want to write the plain string as a parameter you can write it in a variable :

```
<app-my-component [content]=myContent></app-my-component>
```

Comment: It's not the solution I need

Comment: Is there any need to write the content inside the component like you show above ?

What result would you like that you wouldn't have with @Input() ?